# Css - new API -

Tags: css, spotify

I'm trying to migrate my app to the new API, but is there a complete list of the available CSS thru the Framework ?

For example, on previous API, external link were well formated with a small square to show user that it is an external link and I'm not able to do it with new API without doing it myself ?

Comment: we need more details about the framework and styling your trying to achieve.

Comment: As my question is tagged spotify, it seems to me clear for the framework

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: ok, thanks, then thanks to Thomas to be able to understand.

Comment: I agree it's not clear if you're not familiar with the significant revisions to the Spotify App API.  Many things that were easy and built-in are less easy and more freeform.  But, given the spotify tag, it's pretty clear to a spotify app dev.

Comment: For future reference - Spotify has many APIs. Simply tagging "spotify" isn't enough. A single extra sentence explaining which API you're using would've avoided all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll have to do it yourself.  Something like this would work (from http://www.electrictoolbox.com/add-offsite-link-icon-after-external-links-css/)

```
a[href^="http://"] {
    background: url(/images/external.png) center right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 13px;
}
```

Oh, and for the rest of your question, here's the list of css files available: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/index.html

Comment: thanks, I will do it that way.